# Category Descriptions - HTML?

Tags: categories, html, description

Is it possible to allow HTML to be rendered in Category descriptions? My theme uses them quite a lot, and I'd like to style them better with images and links.

This seems to be do-able from what I read elsewhere, but I wondered if there is a best practice to get it to work (I'd prefer not to use a barely supported plugin).

Many thanks,

R

Answer (score 6):

The HTML is stripped by `wp_filter_kses()`. So this should work:

```
remove_filter( 'pre_term_description', 'wp_filter_kses' );
```

When you want to print that content, use `wpautop()`:

```
echo wpautop( term_description() );
```