# Is it possible to add short code and html tag in Category Description?

Tags: categories

I want to add a shortcode (like slider) and html tag like `<h2>-------- text -----</h2>`. Is that possible?

I have already tried but is not really working. Only normal text is showing, no short code or html tag even. Any idea how or not possible?

i want to use this for own theme. i have one product page. but many category (like 7) and each category will have different slideshow banner. and under there product picture and details. i don't want make each category page separately, i can show shortcode from category description then i can it will be work for me.  my shortcode will be `[rev_slider slider]`

category page code

```
 <?php if ( category_description() ) :  ?>
  <div class="catdes"><?php echo wpautop( term_description() ); ?></div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

function page

```
remove_filter( 'pre_term_description', 'wp_filter_kses' );
```

Comment: i found how to show html tag. here it is http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98034/category-descriptions-html >>> i test a it is work

Comment: You will need to explain exactly where you need to implement this and what the outcome should be. Also you will need to add the code that you already have, working or not.

Comment: @PieterGoosen i edited my post. now you can understand more clearly

Comment: i found solution .. it works nicely.. http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/rich-tax-description-editor this plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For displaying shortcodes you can use `do_shortcode`

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( term_description() ); ?>
```

For HTML the filter should be enough (what you posted worked on my install).

```
remove_filter( 'pre_term_description', 'wp_filter_kses' );
```